# Video Calling Library for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, videochat

Is there a library or any way to embed **video chat** capability in a ios application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work at 2600hz, I'm new to stack overflow so if I'm screwing something up, let me know.

You can use Kazoo, our fully open-source cloud voip stack for this, our APIs allow you do all the sip signaling and proxying for Facetime style video connections (we do this for audio calls now, and video works in our lab but we haven't rolled it out to our community yet. Basically you'd need to do some QA).

If you'd like to play with it, I can send you an invite to our hosted cluster OR you can install it directly from our Git repos here: https://github.com/2600hz/kazoo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm actually going to let you know about something you *didn't* screw up: being completely up-front about your affiliation with a project/product/&c. you're suggesting. You'd be surprised how many people conveniently forget to mention that, and even for completely non-commercial projects it's frowned upon. Thanks for being an exception!

Comment: Seeing that you have made several posts today, just a note that *only* posting about your own products will likely trigger the spam alerts.

Comment: Are there any iOS/OSX libraries to interact with Kazoo (e.g. voice calls, im)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are a few solutions:

First of all, no API from Apple.

Second, [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/live-video-ios-sdk) does seem to solve your problem, Client & Server side easily.

If you want to implement it yourself, I know [Spirit](http://www.spiritdsp.com/) & [Vidyo](http://www.vidyo.com/), which are paid VoIP & Video stacks.

You may also use [iDoubs](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/), or [PJSip](http://www.pjsip.org/), both are open-source solutions, but they are using [x264 encoder](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) which its license is GPL and not good enough for the AppStore.

Either way, you'll need a 3rd party library for that & you must have a server side as well (Probably a [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) server).

**If anyone knows more open-source / paid solutions, please share.**

Comment: OpenTok is not free, you can use trial for 30 days

Comment: @avishic What do you mean by `not good enough for the AppStore`? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Build Video Chat Into Your Mobile Apps with OpenTok